# Unusual behaviour with 18446744073709551615ull

Tags: c, max

```
unsigned long long m = 18446744073709551615ull;
unsigned long long i;

for (i=18446744073709551610ull; i<m; ++i) {
            printf("%llu \n", i);
    }
```

This produces the expected result:
18446744073709551610,
18446744073709551611,
18446744073709551612,
18446744073709551613,
18446744073709551614.

```
for (i=18446744073709551610ull; i<m+1; ++i) {
                    printf("%llu \n", i);
                }
```

This prints nothing at all.

```
for (i=18446744073709551610ull; i<=m; ++i) {
                    printf("%llu \n", i);
                }
```

This prints endless 6 digit numbers, starting on a different number each time the programme is run and until the programme is cancelled.
I have been printing all the Pell numbers available in C but want the programme to stop when all the available Pell numbers in C has been reached. However it prints several hundred six digit numbers and then "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" is printed. This means there are four different results when using the maximum number in C. Here is the Pell number code:

```
unsigned long long x = 1, y = 2, z;
unsigned long long pell_series[52];

                        pell_series[0] = 0;
                        pell_series[1] = 1;
                        
                        printf("%d,",0);
                        printf("%d,",1);
                        printf("%d,",2);
            
                        for (int q=2; q<m; q++) {
                        z = x + (y*2);
                        pell_series[q] = z;
                        printf("%llu,", z);
                        x = y;
                        y = z;
                        }
```

I understand C can be unpredictable when using the largest number but even the unpredictability is unpredictable. My question is - is there any way of getting the programme to stop when the maximum number available is reached?

UPDATE:
Thank you for all your replies, they are really insightful. I have just noticed a huge mistake in my code for Pell numbers: instead of q<m, the code should, of course, only run when z is less than m.

Comment: *"I understand C can be unpredictable when using the largest number "* whatever modus of insanity breathed that worthless garbage into your knowledge banks, stop listening to it. On your platform, `ULONG_LONG_MAX` is `18446744073709551615` any attempt at contriving either an increment, or an expression, at +1 that value will result in an overflow (which is defined behavior for unsigned, but that's not really helpful for you). Rather than a loop based on exceeding a limit being the breaking point, consider a loop whose *tail* logic is to `break` when the limit has actually been reached.

Comment: Why don't you print `m` as well? Or `m+1` ?

Comment: Unsigned numbers are very prodictable.

Comment: [Or you could do this](https://godbolt.org/z/YsE4bj)

Comment: ""I understand C can be unpredictable when using the largest number " whatever modus of insanity breathed that worthless garbage into your knowledge banks, stop listening to it." That is what I wanted to hear. I use C for transforming music themes but I read sometime ago when I started learning C that it should "never be used if lives depend on it". This surprised me as I had also been told that C is a very safe language. I'm still learning as you can see.

Comment: @IanStewart Second only to asm, C is as "safe" as the person wielding it, and absolutely no safer. It is excessively belligerent at allowing you to hang yourself, and will not hesitate if you attempt to. I.e. It's as good as you are. Get proficient with it, and you can do amazing things. Don't, and you can do some terrible things very, *very* easily.

Answer (score 2):

#### The `i<m+1` case

`18446744073709551615ull` is the largest value that can be represented by an `unsigned long long` on your platform (64 bits). So `m + 1` overflows, which (for unsigned integers) is defined behaviour: it wraps to 0. Hence `i<m+1` becomes `i<0` which is never true, so the loop doesn't even run once.

#### The `i<=m` case

> This prints endless 6 digit numbers, starting on a different number each time the programme is run and until the programme is cancelled.

That's not what I'm seeing, nor what should happen according to the standard. Are you very sure of this? Here's what should happen...

At some point `i` reaches the maximum value, `18446744073709551615ull`, which is equal to `m` so the loop is entered. Then `++i` increments `i`, causing it to overflow and wrap to 0. Obviously `i<=m` is still true for `i` equal to zero, so the loop body is entered again and starts counting up from zero, *ad infinitum*.

All this is perfectly well-defined behaviour, nothing unpredictable about it (except the size of `unsigned long long` which is implementation-defined).

If you want the loop to run up to *and including* the maximum possible value, you can give `i > 0` as the loop condition. Or, if you prefer to be a bit more explicit, leave the condition empty and put `if (i == m) { break; }` at the end of the loop body.

Answer (score 1):

1. Do not use magic numbers. You have convenient macros defined in the `limits.h` header file

Now answering your question. The first loop executes normally.
The second loop : control variable wraps around and it will never stop. `ULLONG_MAX + 1 == 0`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned long long m = ULLONG_MAX;
    unsigned long long i;

    for (i = ULLONG_MAX - 5; i<m; ++i) {
        printf("%llu \n", i);
    }

    printf("\nWraparound will happen now\n\n");

    for (i=ULLONG_MAX - 5; i<=m; ++i) {
        printf("%llu \n", i);
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/d9j1qv

Why `m+1` case does not work is very easy to test if you print the values of `m` & `m+1`

```
int main(void)
{
    unsigned long long m = ULLONG_MAX;
    unsigned long long i;

    for (i=ULLONG_MAX - 5; i<m+1; ++i) {
        printf("%llu \n", i);
    }

    printf("m = %llu, m+1 == %llu\n", m, m+1);
}
```

```
x86-64 gcc 10.2

Program returned: 0
Program stdout

m = 18446744073709551615, m+1 == 0
```

As you see the condition in the `for` loop will never be met

https://godbolt.org/z/3d4nxT

Answer (score 0):

All is predictable.:)

This loop

```
for (i=18446744073709551610ull; i<m; ++i) {
        printf("%llu \n", i);
}
```

for clarity may be rewritten like

```
for (i = ULLONG_MAX - 5; i < ULLONG_MAX; ++i) {
        printf("%llu \n", i);
}
```

So exactly 5 numbers will be outputted.

In this loop

```
for (i=18446744073709551610ull; i<m+1; ++i) {
         printf("%llu \n", i);
}
```

that may be rewritten like

```
for (i = ULLONG_MAX - 5; i < ULLONG_MAX + 1; ++i) {
        printf("%llu \n", i);
}
```

there is integer overflow in the expression `ULLONG_MAX + 1` that for unsigned integerd numbers yields 0. So in fact you have

```
for (i = ULLONG_MAX - 5; i < 0; ++i) {
        printf("%llu \n", i);
}
```

So neither will be outputted.

In this loop

```
for (i=18446744073709551610ull; i<=m; ++i) {
          printf("%llu \n", i);
}
```

that may be rewritten like

```
for (i = ULLONG_MAX - 5; i <= ULLONG_MAX; ++i) {
        printf("%llu \n", i);
}
```

there is another overflow. At this time there is overflow of the expression `++i`. After `i` is equal to `ULLONG_MAX` the next value of `i` will be `0` and the condition of the loop

```
i <= ULLONG_MAX
```

again evaluates to logical `true`. So you have an infinite loop.

A simple way to stop the loop when the maximum value is achieved is to use for example a do-while loop instead of the for loop.

```
unsigned long long int i = ULLONG_MAX - 5;

do
{
    printf("%llu \n", i);
} while ( i++ != ULLONG_MAX );
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void) 
{
    unsigned long long int i = ULLONG_MAX - 5;
    
    do
    {
        printf( "%llu\n", i );
    } while ( i++ != ULLONG_MAX );      
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
18446744073709551610
18446744073709551611
18446744073709551612
18446744073709551613
18446744073709551614
18446744073709551615
```